# DNS error when pulling Docker image

Tags: dns, docker

So i have Docker running in an Ubuntu Server 18.04 machine. It has been working like a charm till now that i have tried to pull a couple of images and the same error appeared both times. The error says:

```
error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/a0/a0ffee54489d10f657c715811553011e368195865fe39ae3d5fdea8dace66748/data?verify=1589200359-MYPxAKQ8zgEhxMQJTt1LhcvCOO4%3D: dial tcp: lookup production.cloudflare.docker.com on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:38474->[::1]:53: i/o timeout
```

Doing some research i found that production.cloudflare.docker.com is not resolving in that machine altough i can resolve another addresses without problem. Also, a Windows laptop that i have is capable to resolve the docker.com address, so the site is up and running.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you really trying to pull from "production.cloudflare.docker.com"? Cloudfare is a CDN ( big web cache) and this kind of address is not a direct address to use. If you see this there may be Cloudflare problems in your area.

Comment: I am pulling It from Docker Hub. I know about Cloudflare, maybe they are caching from DH. As i said, i can resolve the address from another laptop, not in the same spot but in the same town.